# Weird padding at top UINavigationController while animating to detail in iOS11

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, uikit, ios11

I'm posting here because I'm completely lost on this one.
I've searched all over the web, tried a lot of things myself, and searched weeks on this bug, but I can't find it.

So ever since **iOS 11** (doesn't happen on iOS 10), everytime I press a button that activates the "show" segue in a `UINavigationController` the **animation shows some weird padding at the top**. 
This padding disappears when the animation is finished.

I've changed the backgroundcolor of the superview to a red color, and the **space you can see is indeed from the superview itself**, so my guess is the whole `UITableView` is being moved down for some reason, although I'm not sure what exactly is the cause here. 
(I'm using storyboard and AutoLayout constraints)

Another thing I noticed is that the **spacing/padding you see is different on the iPhone X compared to the other devices** (my guess is that it's the same height as the (non)safe area at the top? Again, not sure.

I don't think code is necessary to be provided here, as I wouldn't really know which part causes this behaviour (and there's a lot of code that I can't share for reasons..).
Any suggestions/help on how to fix this would be deeply appreciated!

**Here are some examples:**

*iPhone X running iOS 11.1 (also happened on 11.0)*
[image: iPhone X]

*iPhone 8 gif*
[image: iPhone 8]

**EDIT:** I should add, some things I already tried:

- `tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never`
- Setting headerviews to 0
- `tableView.setContentOffset(0, animated: false)`
- Playing with the translucency settings of the `UINavigationBar`
- `AutomaticallyAdjustContentInsets` is set to false

Comment: Have you tried looking at the "safe spaces" in the storyboard. Your constraints may be tied to those due to the update for iOS 11. It happened with several of my views and I had to go in and adjust them.

Comment: @SpenserArn yes, I am using the Safe areas in the storyboard, and I tried playing around with them but without success so far. Did you have the same problem? I'll look into it again tomorrow but I doubt it (would be great if it works tho)

Comment: @SpenserArn So, after playing around with them again, it was indeed the Safe Areas that caused the issue! Thank you so much for the suggestion, my day has been made! Stupid that I didn't try a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as suggested by [Spenser-Arn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4163738/spenser-arn), I played around with the constraints and the Safe Areas, turns out, the safe areas where the cause of the issue.

Hope this helps other people as much as it helped me, and a big thankyou to Spenser-Arn!